# VBA UDF for Excel goes VALUE! after using hidden = true on another UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

i've built a Excel worksheet with several formulas for a project. Then, i added a CommandButton for collapse/expand certain cell groups.

CommandButton code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 30
With Me.CommandButton1
    If .Caption = "Customer Relationship" & vbCrLf & "Management Processes" Then
        .Caption = "Customer Relationship" & vbCrLf & "Management Processes "
        Rows("11:74").Hidden = False
    Else
        .Caption = "Customer Relationship" & vbCrLf & "Management Processes"
        Rows("11:74").Hidden = True
    End If
    'Worksheets(1).Calculate
End With
End Sub
```

It works correctly. Now, on the worksheet, i have a cell that uses another UDF to sum cells based on their background color, code for that one is:

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, 
Optional SUM As Boolean)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult
    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

If SUM = True Then
    For Each rCell In rRange
      If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
        vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
      End If
    Next rCell
Else
    For Each rCell In rRange
      If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
        vResult = 1 + vResult
      End If
    Next rCell
End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

And it works like a charm as well. Here comes the issue: When I press the CommandButton, the cells collapse/expands correctly, but the cell with the sum-by-color function goes VALUE!, then if I click on the formula bar inside the formula and back on the worksheet, it automagically fixes itself without me changing anything.

I tried to:
a- Add a recalculate on the button, no dice.
b- Discard the function, i tried with other code, it does the same weird thing.
c- Discard that the formula had gone nuts because it couldn't "see" the collapsed cells anymore. It does see them, when i collapse the group, and "fix" the formula clicking on it, it sums correctly, even if cells are hidden at that moment.

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to look into `Application.Volatile`.

Comment: I looked into it as you suggested. Now the behavior its the same, only that when I click on one of the cells that are using the function, all the others that are using it also fixes themselves.

Comment: Perhaps change `SUM` to another name to avoid conflict with the built in function. What data type are you returning?

Comment: FYI the error occuring in your UDF is "Unable to get the Interior property of the Range class" and it happens when trying to read the ColorIndex of `rColor`. I have no idea why that's getting raised though.

Answer (score 0):

Set (at least) one of the cells mentioned in your Function to Dirty when clicking on the commandbutton. This will trigger a recalculation.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 30
With Me.CommandButton1
    If .Caption = "Customer Relationship" & vbCrLf & "Management Processes" Then
        .Caption = "Customer Relationship" & vbCrLf & "Management Processes "
        Rows("11:74").Hidden = False
    Else
        .Caption = "Customer Relationship" & vbCrLf & "Management Processes"
        Rows("11:74").Hidden = True
    End If
    'Worksheets(1).Calculate
End With
Cells(1, 6).Dirty 'For Cell F1
End Sub
```